# Socket.io pending status

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Websocket/socket.io beginner here.

I am curious about chrome > network > WS (filter) if forever pending in socket is normal?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhWZa.png)

I wonder if it is always forever as it is looking for requests?

I will appreciate if someone can explain me why.

Comment: no it shouldnt be like that forever

Comment: The column is 'request timing' which will tell you how long a request took. If the websocket is still open, the request has not ended.

Comment: [Minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is always good to see so we can reproduce the behavior easily.